# Not able to upload more than one image using Spring 4.1.1 and camel 2.14.0

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, restlet

I have an existing code like below one that uploads a single image.

```
public class ImageRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        getContext().setTracing(true);
        getContext().setStreamCaching(true);

        from("servlet:///PushImage?servletName=CamelServlet")
        .to("direct:doImageUploadJob")
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
    
        from("direct:doImageUploadJob")
        .process(new Processor() {
            
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                Message in = exchange.getIn();
                Set<String> names = in.getAttachmentNames();
                Object[] arrayNames = names.toArray();
                System.out.println("image array size::"+ arrayNames.length);
                
                Map<String, DataHandler> attchmentMaps = in.getAttachments();
                System.out.println("image map size::"+ attchmentMaps.size());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in web.xml following configuration is there.

```
    <!-- Camel servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Camel servlet mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/exmpattrn/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But if I try to upload more than one image by calling this API through Postman, it is uploading only the last image selected.
I tried to print the attachment size, but it is always printing as 1.
I don't know why.
Can anybody help me?

I am using Spring 4.1.1 with Java 7.
I am using camel Apache Camel 2.14.0 restlet to form APIs.

Comment: that's a very old version of camel, I'd suggest to upgrade to a newer one

Comment: I am sorry to say that it is not an option with me right now. I need to make changes in the existing version itself